# SVN-LDAP group auth

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, ldap, svn

i want to give access to SVN to specific LDAP (AD) group (svn_access), this configuration works on old server but on the new one it's not.
My config

```
 <Location />
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/html/svn/
   SVNListParentPath on
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "SVN Server"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://yy.yy.yy.yy/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
   AuthLDAPBindDN "read_user@domain.com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "PASSWORD"
   Require ldap-group CN=svn_access,OU=SVN,DC=domain,DC=com
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/svn_auth
 </Location>
```

SVN log

```
AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=svn_access,OU=SVN,DC=domain,DC=com: denied (no authenticated user yet)
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://yy.yy.yy.yy/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting tat
Path to authz file is /etc/subversion/svn_auth
Access granted: 'tat' OPTIONS REPO1:/
```

The problem is that it accept any user in AD, even if it not in "svn_access" group.
Thanks for help.

Comment: No ideas? Still don't know why this happening